# Where to place angular element so it can effected all scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this code which is a contenteditable placeholder by CraigStuntz.

My question is where should I put this code so all the `div` which contain `contenteditable` will get effected.

I tried to put under `app.controller('myCtrl', function(){});` but it only works with the direct scope. No nested scope is working.

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable]')).bind('change keydown keypress input', function() {
    if (this.textContent) {
        this.setAttribute('data-contenteditable-placeholder', 'true');
    }
    else {
        this.removeAttribute('data-contenteditable-placeholder');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can create a reusable directive and put it inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a directive like this.

```
angular.module('angularProject.directives', [])
.directive('placeholder', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(elem) {
            elem.bind('change keydown keypress input', function() {
                elem.setAttribute('data-contenteditable-placeholder', 'true');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

You can then place it in any of your divs like this.

```
<div placeholder></div>
```

I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can create a directive for this task